# Segment out peak to peak of graph to get 1 period python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pdb

file = open("Data1r2.txt", 'r')
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()
```

So what i am trying to get is to have the code use the data from the txt file and plot out a graph. what im stuck with is i cant figure out how to have peak detection have for the graph to show the peaks,  since i need to calculate the value from 1 peak to another.

```
t = []
z = []
y = []
x = []

for line in lines:

  parts = line.split(", ")
  if len(parts) > 3:
column1 = parts[3].split(':')
column2 = column1[1]

column3 = parts[2].split(':')
column4 = column3[1]

column5 = parts[1].split(':')
column6 = column5[1]

column7 = parts[0].split(':')
column8 = column7[1]

T = column2[0:len(column2)]
Z = column4[0:len(column4)]
Y = column6[0:len(column6)]
X = column8[0:len(column8)]
```

To set the trace

```
T1 = float(T)
t.append(T1)

Z1 = float(Z)
z.append(Z1)

Y1 = float(Y)
y.append(Y1)

X1 = float(X)
x.append(X1)
```

plotting the graph

```
  plt.plot(t,z,label='z')
  plt.plot(t,y,label='y')
  plt.plot(t,x,label='x')
  plt.legend()
  plt.show()
```

[Sample of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hlh9s.jpg)

[image: Graph]

i wanna be able to cut out the graphs peak to peak for 1 period

Comment: Looking at you sample data I feel that peak-to-peak is to unreliable for your purpose. I propose using an analysis over more than one period, e.g. a fourier analysis. FFT, find the maximum of that, then factor in the phase of that frequency.

Comment: i have no idea how to do that as im new to python, and programming sadly

Comment: Wait for other comments or maybe answers. Maybe it is not the only way to go. But if mine stays the only feedback you get, the path is going to get a little "stony". Do some research. I can't name one, but it would be very un-pythony if there were nothing already available for that job. Then look for a tutorial. (Sorry, asking for such a lib would be off-topic and asking how to do it too broad.) This question as is does not seem too off-topic in my opinion by the way. If you did some experiments with a lib, then asking for help here when stuck seems OK, too.

Comment: I basically agree with @Yunnosch, even if I'm not sure if the resolution of the sample data would be much better suited for an FFT. However, if you want to start with peak detection, you could try `argrelmax` (and its colleagues `argrelmin` and `argrelextrema`) from `scipy.signal`. As it is able to return the indices of all local extrema (after some playing around with its parameter `order`), it also can be used to take several periods into account by taking mean value, for example... And one additional hint: If you expect someone to give an example, you should post a sample of your data, too.

Comment: ok, ive added the data sample